# Which value should I use for NSURLRequestCachePolicy for NSURLRequest?

Tags: ios7, nsurlrequest, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

NSURLRequest +requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval: has a cache policy.

The documentation in XCode5 lists an enum with four constants and immediately below lists seven different constants. The documentation is inconsistant. Which options work, and which ones should I use?

Answer (score 0):

NRURLRequest.h has the seven constants documented, and two of those are marked as not implemented (no mention of that in the documentation by the way).

So if you want to use NSURLRequestCachePolicy, check the header file for accurate documentation.